# CloudStack management server on VPS and VPS Host?

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I am aware of CloudStack management server running on VPS, but can a host be another VPS or multiple VPSes?

Instead of using physical baremetal servers, can we use big VPSes or cloud servers like AWS?

Forgive me if my question is silly. I have researched quit, i.e, searching on search engines and forums but could not find proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The host cannot be another VPS or cloud computing provider.

The host needs to be one of the supported cloudstack hypervisors which includes:

- Vmware ESXi
- HyperV
- XenServer
- KVM